# Using forward Euler scheme to approximate Cauchy equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, wave-equation

Let $\frac{du}{dt} - \frac{du}{dx}=0$.

$u(x,0) = e^x, u(1,t) = e^{t+1}$

I've been asked to write up a finite difference scheme using the forward Euler method for the step $\tau$ for t and the backward Euler for the step h for x.

I've gotten: [$\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{\tau}-G(t_n,u_n)$]-[$\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{h}-G(t_{n+1},u_{n+1})$]=0.

Now I need to compute (by hand) the approximate solution given h=1/4, $\tau =1/2$, and a few values for t. How would I do this?

Comment: Discretising the PDE $$u_{t} = u_{x}$$ using FE on time ($k$), BE on space ($n$) yields

$$\frac{u^{k+1}_{n+1} - u^{k}_{n+1}}{\tau} = \frac{u^{k}_{n+1} - u^{k}_{n}}{h}$$

Now rewrite so you have $u^{k+1}_{n+1}$ on the RHS, everything else on the LHS.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I was using ODE formulas by mistake